# Compilation of x264 with newest libswscale and libavformat

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ffmpeg, compilation, x264

Yesterday I wanted to compile x264 myself because the latest binary on videolan is compiled without libswscale: [link](http://download.videolan.org/pub/videolan/x264/binaries/linux-x86_64/)

If I just use

```
./configure --enable-static --enable-shared
```

then the binary will compile libswscale 3.1.101 and libavformat 56.40.101 from the libswscale-dev and libavformat-dev packages. If I clone FFmpeg's git and use

```
./configure --enable-static --enable-shared --extra-cflags="-I$HOME/FFmpeg"
```

the binary will have the latest libswscale and libavformat, but it wont work:

```
pc@pcroland:~/bin$ ./x264 --version
x264 0.148.2744 b97ae06
(libswscale 4.3.101)
(libavformat 57.58.101)
built on Dec  4 2016, gcc: 5.4.0 20160609
x264 configuration: --bit-depth=8 --chroma-format=all
libx264 configuration: --bit-depth=8 --chroma-format=all
x264 license: GPL version 2 or later
libswscale/libavformat license: GPL version 2 or later
pc@pcroland:~/bin$ ./x264 --input-res 1920x1080 --fps 24000/1001 --vf resize:720,404,method=spline --output /home/pc/test.264 /home/pc/asd.264
[h264 @ 0x1bc3ec0] Format h264 detected only with low score of 1, misdetection possible!
[h264 @ 0x1bc3ec0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: h264, none): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
lavf [error]: could not find input stream info
avs [error]: failed to load avisynth
raw [info]: 1920x1080p 0:0 @ 24000/1001 fps (cfr)
resize [info]: resizing to 720x404
x264 [info]: using SAR=404/405
x264 [info]: using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 AVX2 LZCNT BMI2
x264 [info]: profile High, level 3.0
Bus error (core dumped)
pc@pcroland:~/bin$
```

How to reproduce the error:

```
cd; git clone https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg; git clone http://git.videolan.org/git/x264.git; cd x264; ./configure --enable-static --enable-shared --extra-cflags="-I$HOME/FFmpeg" --bindir="$HOME/bin"; sudo make; sudo make install
```

System: Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: I repeated your steps to reproduce the error, but everything goes well.

Comment: Your log says that the problem is not x264 compilation or libavformat but your input sample: /home/pc/asd.264. Looks like it is not really H.264 sample. As for why it crash after that when taking your input as raw I am dunno without gdb backtrace.

Comment: The video was indeed the problem, but the x264 binary still doesn't work:
*** stack smashing detected ***: ./x264 terminated
Aborted (core dumped)